# Java Hibernate Id Question

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any way I could generate a four digit number from the AutoGenerated Id that the entity creates?
For example: Person has a unique #1. And I would like to create another number that looks like  1001. 
Person #130 would be 1130. I don't think my table is going to be over 9999.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sequence generator and make the sequence start at 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another method inside the entity class that uses the generated Hibernate id, like:

```
public String getNumber() {
    return "#" + Integer.toString(1000 + this.id);
}
```

The only problem is that you have to save the object first, before this method returns a meaningful value.